# I can't use third party assertions like it fit describe fdescribe on Testcafe

Tags: javascript, testing, chai, testcafe, assertion

I would like to run tests from another fixtures using assertions like: `.describe` `.it` `.fit` `.test`, etc

I already import the Testcafe module:

```js
import { testcafe} from 'testcafe';
```

Or

```js
import { t, Selector, describe} from 'testcafe';
```

And I tried many other combinations but always I get the same error.

I have installed locally the last version of `Testcafe` and I have installed the latest chai package.

I am on windows 11 with the last version of `node.js`.

This is the error:

`_index.X is not a function`

Where "X" is any of these: fit it describe fdescribe, etc

Note: Other functions as fixture, test, constructor, are working without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Test API](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402632/api#test-api) there's only one global function: `test`, which fulfills and combines the roles of both `describe` and `it` from jest or similar.

Comment: But I already trying importing "test" with this format: import { test } from 'testcafe'.I received the same error, for this scenario the error is: _index.X is not a function

Comment: We're going to need to know more about your setup, a reproducible example would be great